# AWS service that provides watchdog functionality for a service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, watchdog

I have developed a service that receives messages from AWS/Kinesis and process them. I'd like to have a watchdog service that will catch processing failures. Before the service starts message processing it sends a message to watchdog and after it finishes processing the message it notifies Watchdog that processing completed successfully. If there is no 'success' message after some timeout period Watchdog should fire some event.

The question is: which AWS service, if any, can do this job for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SNS, making the service publish a notification to the subscriber (watchdog) for each event that you want to be notified about.

> Amazon SNS is a fully managed pub/sub messaging service that makes it easy to decouple and scale microservices, distributed systems, and serverless applications. With SNS, you can use topics to decouple message publishers from subscribers, fan-out messages to multiple recipients at once, and eliminate polling in your applications. SNS supports a variety of subscription types, allowing you to push messages directly to Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) queues, AWS Lambda functions, and HTTP endpoints. AWS services, such as Amazon EC2, Amazon S3 and Amazon CloudWatch, can publish messages to your SNS topics to trigger event-driven computing and workflows. SNS works with SQS to provide a powerful messaging solution for building cloud applications that are fault tolerant and easy to scale.

https://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Comment: Thank you @Adam for your answer. I think that SNS is not a perfect solution because it sends notifications immediately, while it will be better if I'll be able to cancel notification if finished message processing  before timeout period. With out an ability to cancel notifications watchdog service will have to handle all messages but not only messages that were not processed in time